Visual Studio 2022 - C# code behind is not recognized within <script runat="server"> .aspx page
I am having some issues with a new laptop build.  I have a VS 2022 solution that has .aspx pages that do not recognize the C# code within the script tags.  I'm pretty sure I have missed something during the install process, but I'm unable to pinpoint it.  Any help is highly appreciated
Any of my C# code in .aspx page within script tag

you need to install VS2019 side by side with VS2022 to get support for older versions of Framework. You can still use 2022 as the IDE

@pthomson I installed 2019.  At first it didn't seem to take.  But after reopening VS a couple times it looks like all is good now.  Thanks!
